# Substitute character not enclosed by brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string containing curly brackets and I want to replace any character A, which is not contained in a pair of opening and closing brackets, by another character B. So

> ABCDACD{ACDA}ABCD

should be replaced by

> BBCDBCD{ACDA}BBCD

How can I do this with a regex (e.g. in Perl)? Brackets are not nested, but a solution working also for the nested case would be better.

**EDIT:** Changed wording

Comment: Non-nested: `A(?![^{}]*\})` - check that the next bracket after A (if any) is not a closing one. Now let me look for a good dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression, match characters outside curly braces { }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032016/regular-expression-match-characters-outside-curly-braces)

Comment: *"a solution working also for the nested case would be better"* Why, if your data doesn't have nested braces? A non-nested solution is straightforward, but a recursive pattern is necessary for nested braces.

Comment: @NicolasMalebranche: would you please clarify does your statement _"I want to replace a character A by another character B, if it is not contained in a pair of opening and closing brackets."_ actually means _"if the replacement value B is inside the the braces then you don't replace A by B anywhere"_?

Comment: @NicolasMalebranche: what is the expected result of the `ABCDACD{ABCDA}ABCD` input string (please notice the `B` inside the brackets)? Should it be `BBCDBCD{ABCDA}BBCD` (all `A`s outside brackets replaced) or `ABCDACD{ABCDA}ABCD` (the original string unchanged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38696658/4295017) has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697800/4295017) before.

Perl implementation will be different in substitution evaluation part but the [main idea](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) is the same:

Match undesired context (i.e. `{.*?}`) or desired substring (`A`) (in that particular order) using alternation capturing the matches. Then substitute the undesired capture with itself and the desired one with your replacement depending on which part has matched:

```
my $input = "ABCDACD{ACDA}ABCD";
$input =~ s/({.*?})|(A)/{$2 ? "B" : $1}/ge;
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/bK4c1Y

Comment: Your regex is wrong , if B is inside the curly brace then it fails https://ideone.com/kPFT0G

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman, The output in your link is `BBCDBCD{ABCDA}BBCD`. What exactly is wrong there?

Comment: Op wrote : " I want to replace a character A by another character B, if it is not contained in a pair of opening and closing brackets." which means if the replacement value B is inside the the braces then you don't replace A by B anywhere

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman: I think you misunderstood, OP wants to replace `A` by `B` when `A` is not inside curlybrackets

Comment: So, I deleted the answer... feel like fool for the misleading question and lack of sample i/o :|

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl solution that does the job in steps. First it splits the string into chunks of braced/not braced items. Then does the substitution on the not-braced items, and finally puts the items back together again:

```
my $str = 'ABCDACD{ACDA}ABCD';
$str = do {
    my $i = 1; 
    join '', map {$i++ % 2 && $_ =~ s/A/B/g; $_ } split /(\{.*?\})/, $str 
};
```